# Extract numbers from a string pattern

Tags: java, string

I have a file which have details about a parameter called "leak". There is one line in the file that gives this information. "Leaks" have three types; short, medium and long. Not all leaks may be presented at a given time. Below are some examples of leak information in 6 files. The pattern is type_of_leak(number_of_leaks).

e.g:

```
leak:   short(4)    medium(11)  long(4)
leak:   short(6)
leak:   long(3)
leak:   medium(4)   
leak:   medium(1)   long(8)
leak:   short(1)    long(5)
```

I want to extract the three leak values in order and populate an interger array. 0th element short leak, 1st element medium leak and 2nd element long leak. If leaks are not presented for a given category the value should be '0'. Below is the code I'm using. My code can extract the leaks however when the number of leaks is a number more than 1 digit it can only extract the first digit.

```
int[] leaks = new int[3];

if(line.contains("leak:")){ //search for the line that starts with leak

    System.out.println(line);

    //short leaks
    if(line.contains("short")) {
        int index = line.indexOf("short");
        int numShortLeaks = Integer.parseInt((line.substring(index+6, index+7)));
        leaks[0] = numShortLeaks;
    }else {
        leaks[0] = 0; //no short leaks replace with zero                    
    }

    if(line.contains("medium")) {
        int index = line.indexOf("medium");
        int numMediumLeaks = Integer.parseInt((line.substring(index+7, index+8)));
        leaks[1] = numMediumLeaks;
    }else {
        leaks[1] = 0;                       
    }

    if(line.contains("long")) {
        int index = line.indexOf("long");
        int numLongLeaks = Integer.parseInt((line.substring(index+5, index+6)));
        leaks[2] = numLongLeaks;
    }else {
        leaks[2] = 0;                       
    }
```

Comment: It is because your subString only return 1 digit. Try split input and then apply regex to find the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/jeP1ze/1/)

```
/leak:(?:\s+short\((\d+)\))?(?:\s+medium\((\d+)\))?(?:\s+long\((\d+)\))?
```

This will match the short, medium and long ints in group 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

Even if one or more of short, medium, long is not provided, the group number will be correct, so group 3 is always the long value, regardless of whether short/medium were provided.

```
String line = "leak:   short(16)    long(3)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("leak:(?:\\s+short\\((\\d+)\\))?(?:\\s+medium\\((\d+)\\))?(?:\\s+long\\((\\d+)\\))?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {

  //Stick them in your array.
  System.out.println("short " + matcher.group(1)); //16
  System.out.println("medium " + matcher.group(2)); //null
  System.out.println("long  " + matcher.group(3)); //3
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry about the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

By an example

> leak:   short(4)    medium(11)  long(4)

The code is simple as

```
int leakIndex = line.indexOf("leak:");
if(leakIndex > -1) {
    // Got the data
    // 1. Split by tab to group like short(4) or medium(11) or long(4)
    final String[] dataLine = line.subString(leakIndex + 1, line.length).split("\t");
    // 2. Loop over the data line to extract the value
    for(String data : dataLine) {
        // I suggest you to create a sub function to extract
        // 3. Simple idea is replaced all non number by empty value and we can parse it
        if(data.contains("short")) {
            leaks[0] = Integer.parseInt(data.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
            // TODO: You should handling NumberFormatException here
        } else if() {
        }
        // Do other for medium and long here
} else {
// Skip
}
```

Note that: By store a long value into Int cause a loss

Comment: Thank you for the answer. First I tried your suggestion but the regex looked simpler.